# I want to compare 2 hash sets and take out the differences

Tags: c#, hashset

I have 2 hash sets like this.

```
Hash_1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Hash_2 = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
```

I am using C#

I want to compare those two sets and want to get the output like

```
Hash_3 = {1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is: Hash_1 without Hash_2, and Hash_2 without Hash_1, then combined into one set.

So let's start with Hash_1 without Hash_2:

```
var modified1 = Hash_1.Except(Hash_2);
```

and then Hash_2 without Hash_1:

```
var modified2 = Hash_2.Except(Hash_1);
```

And now let's combine them:

```
var result = modified1.Concat(modified2);
```

Or in short:

```
var result = Hash_1.Except(Hash_2).Concat(Hash_2.Except(Hash_1));
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/PTTY56712)

Answer (score 6):

Or you could use [`SymmetricExceptWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.symmetricexceptwith?view=netframework-4.8)

> Modifies the current `HashSet<T>` object to contain only elements that
> are present either in that object or in the specified collection, but
> not both.

```
var h1 = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var h2 = new HashSet<int>() { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

h1.SymmetricExceptWith(h2);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", h1));
```

**Output**

```
1,2,3,7,6,8
```

Internally it just uses

```
foreach (T item in other)
{
   if (!Remove(item))
   {
      AddIfNotPresent(item);
   }
}
```

[**Source Code here**](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.core/R/cc11181fcf60e936.html)

Comment: Oooh. Fancy. I like it!

Comment: @John yeah never used it before actually, that was my first rodeo